# How can create text inside doughnut chart by using Apache poi 5.0.0

Tags: apache-poi

I have created the doughnut chart by using Apache poi 5, but not able to add text inside doughnut hole .

XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 6, 9);

```
                XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
                XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
                legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.BOTTOM);
                
                XSSFSheet hidden = wb.createSheet("Data");
                wb.setSheetHidden(1, true);
                row = hidden.createRow(0);
                cell = row.createCell(0);
                cell.setCellValue("Completed ("+(int)completed+")");
                cell = row.createCell(1);
                cell.setCellValue("Pending ("+(int)pending+")");
                row = hidden.createRow(1);
                cell = row.createCell(0);
                cell.setCellValue(completed);
                cell = row.createCell(1);
                cell.setCellValue(pending);
                
                XDDFDataSource<String> cat = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(hidden,new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, 1));
                XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> val = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(hidden,new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 0, 1));

                
                XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.DOUGHNUT, null, null);// chart.createData(ChartTypes.PIE,
                data.setVaryColors(true);
                XDDFChartData.Series series=data.addSeries(cat, val); 
                chart.setTitleText("Current Status");
                chart.setTitleOverlay(true);
                
                chart.getCTChart().getTitle().getTx().getRich().getPArray(0).getRArray(0).addNewRPr().setB(true);
                chart.getCTChart().getTitle().getTx().getRich().getPArray(0).getRArray(0).getRPr().setSz(1000);
                
                
                chart.plot(data);
                chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).addNewHoleSize().setVal(50);
                 int pointCount = series.getCategoryData().getPointCount();
                  for (int p = 0; p < pointCount; p++) {
                    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDPt().addNewIdx().setVal(p);
                    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDPtArray(p)
                      .addNewSpPr().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(colors[p]);
                  }
```

Comment: You can [edit] your question to show us the relevant code.

Comment: How would you add text inside doughnut hole using `Excel` GUI?

Comment: I try to add shape inside doughnut chart and add text inside shape, but still shape not visible. It looks shape is behind the chart. Is there any way to keep shape on the chart by using Apache?